# NullPointerException in Android while getting Writable Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am making a simple app in android. I am not able to run the program, the logcat shows this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.tasks/com.sample.tasks.ToDo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

After examinations, it looks like their problem in this statement:

```
db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

or this statement:

```
final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE tasks(sno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
    public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "SNo";
    public static final String KEY_TASKS =  "Tasks";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Records";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Tasks";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context context;
    private DbHelper DBHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    { 
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
    DbHelper(Context context)
    {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        db.execSQL("Create Table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_TASKS + " TEXT )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
                System.out.println("Updating the Database");
                onCreate(db);
    }

}
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
    DBHelper.close();
    System.out.println("In close");
    }

    public long createEntry(String task){
        .....
    }

    public String[] getData() {
        .....
    }

}
```

I have tried looking for objects which are not initialized (thus, null) but couldn't find anything.  Kindly help me, what am I missing?

**UPDATE**:

Here is the main part of the other file involved:

```
public class ToDo extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.to_do);


        String[] tasks = new String[16];

        //Retrive tasks from database and view it on the screen
        DBAdapter info = new DBAdapter(this);
        info.open();
        tasks = info.getData();
        info.close();
    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.tasks/com.sample.tasks.ToDo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.sample.tasks.DBAdapter$DbHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:46)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.sample.tasks.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:60)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.sample.tasks.ToDo.onCreate(ToDo.java:59)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-15 16:11:19.187: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: post full stacktrace and the code where you call open()

Comment: Simply, it cannot find your database. make sure your opening and from the correct path.

Comment: @njzk2 What is stacktrace and where do I find it in eclipse? are you taking about the error messages in LogCat?

Comment: the long red text in the logcat somewhere near `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.tasks/com.sample.tasks.ToDo}: java.lang.NullPointerException` It contains the content of the call stack where your crashed, as well as the line where it crashed.

Comment: @njzk2 I have edited my question to include the code where open() is called.

Comment: @njzk2 I have included the stacktrace in the question

Comment: replace db by arg0 in DbHelper.onCreate. You are executing your query on another object that is not initialized. arg0 is the newly created database that you must use at this point.

Comment: quick note on the stacktrace : it gives you the exact point of crash `at com.sample.tasks.DBAdapter$DbHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:46)` with the line number.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks a lot. I was struggling for hours. being aware of default arguments from auto-generated funtions - it's a lesson for life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question, as given by njzk2 in comments,

In the onCreate() method of the DBAdapter class, change the argument from arg0 to db. You are currently executing your query on another object that is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Before Calling the `db.execSQL` function in your `onCreate` method, call 
`db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDBPath", MODE_PRIVATE, null);`.  This method will create the database if it does not exist already, or open it if it exists.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for a full description of the function.

Comment: What should i write instead of "MyDBPath"?

Comment: disagree. onCreate is called because of the call to openOrCreateDatabase (which is a Context class), or getWritableDatabase. I never use openOrCreateDatabase.

Comment: You can use something like "MyDB".  Its just referencing the database saved on the local file system.